# не передается переменная

Tags: javascript

```
$(function(){
  var container = $('figure'),
    iframe = $('iframe'),
    $window = $(window),
    coord = container.offset().top + container.outerHeight(),
    scroll = $window.scrollTop();
  $window.on('scroll', function () {
    iframe.toggleClass('sticky', scroll > coord);
    iframe.toggleClass('sticky', $window.scrollTop() > coord);
  })  
})
```

почему то, что выделено жирным не работает, а то, что курсивом - работает?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На самом деле все работает.

Отличие заключается в том, что при событии `scroll`, меняется значение, которое возвращает `$window.scrollTop()`, а так как ты сохранил это значение вначале, в самом обработчике у тебя `scroll > coord` будет постоянно одно и то же.

Во втором варианте, при каждой прокрутке получается разное значение из `$window.scrollTop()`, поэтому результат проверки условия `$window.scrollTop() > coord` может отличаться, в зависимости от текущего положения.